# How can I move focus from any other tool window to text editor in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-10

For an example after I go to the Project tab with `Alt+1` shortcut and open specific file with pressing `Enter` I then want to go and edit content with single shortcut. Is there any way to do it?

There is couple of things that I can use, but neither does exactly what I want:

- `Ctrl+Tab` - that opens the switcher and selects next file in switcher instead of allowing me to edit file with single `Ctrl+Tab`
- `Ctrl+E` or `Ctrl+Shift+E` do different things but basically the result is simmilar as above

What I want is to simply edit the file after opening it with keyboard from  Projects tab (without using mouse).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I move focus from any other tool window to text editor in PhpStorm?

Just press <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

Works in every tool window. For built-in Terminal though you can (may have to) configure different shortcut for such action (as `Esc` can be needed there).

---

> For an example after I go to the Project tab with `Alt+1` shortcut and open specific file with pressing `Enter` I then want to go and edit content with single shortcut. Is there any way to do it?

Use <kbd>F4</kbd> for that (action is available in context menu and called `Jump to Source`).

---

> `Ctrl+Tab` - that opens the switcher and selects next file in switcher instead of allowing me to edit file with single `Ctrl+Tab`

Just press and release it quickly: it works just like <kbd>Alt + Tab</kbd> on Windows. If you keep modifier key pressed (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in this particular case) it will keep the Switcher window opened.

Comment: Worked perfectly. <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>F4</kbd> was what i was looking for. Tried loads of things but this did not cross my mind. Thank you @LazyOne (hah this sounds so good)